# Is there a way to get current function name, from within an enclosing scope?

Tags: kotlin

Simply, given:

```
class Foo {
    fun foo() = runBlocking {
        bar()
    }
}

inline suspend fun <reified T> T.bar() {
    coroutineScope {
        println(T::class.simpleName) // I want this to output 'Foo'
    }
}
```

...I want to get 'Foo' as my output. I think it's not feasible, but thought I'd ask just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

`runBlocking` has `this: CoroutineScope` parameter and your function `bar()` runs on this CoroutineScope instance, not on Foo class instance.

```
fun foo() = runBlocking {
    this@Foo.bar()
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to get this result from just modifying `bar()`? If for example I could write `inline suspend fun <reified T> T.foo() where T : not CoroutineScope`, it would do what I want, but afaik this syntax isn't supported.